# Ping test batch file not working?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ping

I have been working on a simple little project, but the batch code refuses to work. Can anyone help fix this? It either tells me that the ip must be specified or the ping result just doesn't show up.

```
@echo off

echo       :1 Minecraft server resolver 
echo       :2 Website resolver
echo       :3 Ping test
echo       :4 Crash this computer
echo       Please enter your selection 
set /p whatapp=
cls

if %whatapp%==1 (
    echo         Please enter the IP of the Minecraft server you wish to resolve   
    set /p x=IP=
    set n=1
    PING %x% -n 1
    call :Pingtest 
    pause > nul
:Pingtest
    IF %errorlevel% EQU 1 (echo Server is Offline) else (GOTO:EOF)
    pause
) else if %whatapp%==2 (
    codetoinstallapp2
) else (
    echo invalid choice
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10558905/5047996) for your code to work since you are assigning and reading a variable inside of a code block:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

if %whatapp%==1 (
    set /p x=IP=
    ping !x! -n 1
)
endlocal
```

In addition you need to move the `:PINGTEST` section outside of the `if %whatapp%` block to the very end of your script, and place a `goto :EOF` before it to not fall into it unintentionally.

Answer (score 2):

1. [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables can
>   be referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%`)

2. Mixed `CALL :Pingtest` with reaching the `:Pingtest` label by normal code pass.
3. Using `GOTO` [or even `:label` within parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404) - including `FOR` and `IF` commands - [will break their context](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html).
4. A successful/unsuccessful `PING` does NOT always return an `%errorlevel%` of `0` / `1`.
   Therefore [to reliably detect a successful ping](http://ss64.com/nt/ping.html) - pipe the output into `FIND` and look for the text "`TTL`"

Hence, use

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
color 02
echo(---
echo       :1 Minecraft server resolver 
echo       :2 Website resolver
echo       :3 Ping test
echo       :4 Crash this computer
echo       Please enter your selection 
set /p whatapp=
cls

if %whatapp%==1 (
  cls
  color 02
  echo( ---
  echo         Please enter the IP of the Minecraft server you wish to resolve   
  set /p x=IP=
  set n=1
  PING !x! -n 1|FIND /I "TTL="
REM   call :Pingtest 
REM   pause > nul
REM   :Pingtest
  echo !errorlevel!
  IF !errorlevel! EQU 1 (echo Server !x! is Offline) else (
    echo Server !x! is Online
    rem next code here
    REM GOTO:EOF
  )
  pause

) else if %whatapp%==2 (
  codetoinstallapp2
) else (
  echo invalid choice
)
```