# Renaming "!" and '-"

Tags: batch-file, edit

I have a large batch file that searches %CD% and sub-directory's and ether moves, copies or deletes files of my choosing.
I have ran into a problem where the .bat file will pass over files of any type if they have certain symbols in their name like (!,-).
Is their a way to have a batch file search %CD% and sub-directory's for files that contain these symbols and rename them with their current name without the symbols?
For argument sake lets just use the (!) symbol, and I can edit in the rest.
Thank you in advance.

EDIT---------------------------------------------------
Here is part of my code I am using. I do not have one for what I am trying to accomplish at the moment.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set /p folder1=Folder Name:
set TESTFOLDER=%folder1%
set /p Type=Enter File Type:
set /p copymove=Copy or Move:
set /p directory=DIR:
md "%TESTFOLDER%"

set /a counter=0
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B /A-D "%directory%\""*.%Type%"') DO FOR      /F "tokens=*" %%j IN ('DIR /B "%%i"') DO IF EXIST ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j" (
    set /a counter=!counter!+1
    echo folder: %TESTFOLDER%
    %copymove% "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\"%%j_!counter!.%Type%""
) ELSE %copymove% "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j"

:eof
```

Comment: All I really need is the code to search and rename all files without the symbols. I do not mind it being a separate Batch file, I can always call: it if I have to.

Comment: Can a known command "CD"  use an environmental variable of the same name %CD%.    I thought some of the environment variables like %DIR%  %DEL% were special in that they set default command line options or other details specific to the command.

Comment: Im sorry Wql Surfer you lost me, I have not been making .Bat file for very long but, I'm catching on. So I'm not real sure what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

Stay on safe side with proper quoting and *delayed expansion disabled*:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set /p "folder1=Folder Name: "
if not defined folder1 set "folder1=33721424"
set "TESTFOLDER=%folder1%"
md "%TESTFOLDER%" 2>NUL

set /p "Type=Enter File Type: "
if not defined type set "type=txt"

rem set /p copymove=Copy or Move:
choice /C CM /M "Copy or Move"
if %errorlevel% EQU 2 (set "copymove=move") else (set "copymove=copy")

set /p "directory=DIR: "
if not defined directory set "directory=D:\bat\Unusual Names" 

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR /S /B /A-D "%directory%\*.%Type%"') DO (
    set "_fileToMove=%%i"
    set "_filename=%%~ni"
    set "_fileexte=%%~xi"
    call :copy_move
)
:endscript
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof

:copy_move
set "_filennew=%_filename%"
set /a "counter=0"
:cmLoop
set /a "counter+=1"
IF EXIST ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%_filennew%%_fileexte%" (
    set "_filennew=%_filename%_%counter%"
    goto :cmLoop
)
echo "%_filennew%%_fileexte%"
%copymove% "%_fileToMove%" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%_filennew%%_fileexte%" >NUL
goto :eof
```

Explanation:

- consistently use `%`-expansion. All `cmd`-poisonous characters (e.g. valid folder name and/or extension `a&b` or `c!d`) in user's response to `set /p` (as well as file paths obtained from `dir /S /B` command) are escaped using double quotes;
- prevent user's accidentally wrong response `cop` or even despiteful input `2>NUL del /Q` or even `del /Q *.* & del` to `copymove` variable, cf. `choice` and consequent `if` instead of primitive `set /p`;
- `FOR /F "delims=" ...` as `"tokens=*"` would remove trailing spaces (although this is not the case of `%%i` but could be useful in `%%j` in your original code);
- omitted inner `%%j` loop using `%%~ni` and `%%~nxi` [Parameter Extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html);
- note that `2>NUL` [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) in `md "%TESTFOLDER%" 2>NUL` suppresses possible `A subdirectory or file a already exists` error message;
- analogously, suppressed possible `File Not Found` message by `dir` command; note [escaped `>` as `2>NUL`](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) in `FOR` loop command argument;
- if a file  (e.g. `abc.txt`) exists in target folder, then above above code would copy/move it to first available filename from `abc_1.txt`, `abc_2.txt`, `abc_3.txt` ... sequence;
- `:copy_move` subroutine: necessary as [using `GOTO` within parentheses](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) - including `FOR` and `IF` commands - will break their context ([or even `:label` as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404));
- `:eof` label omitted, see [`goto :eof` meaning](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html);
- `if not defined ...`: **what-if** user's response to any of `set /P` commands would be only hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

**Output** (second run on my ancient data set):

```
==> D:\bat\SO\33721424.bat
Folder Name:
Enter File Type:
Copy or Move [C,M]?C
DIR:
"01exclam!ation_1.txt"
"02exc!lam!ation_1.txt"
"11per%cent_1.txt"
"12per%cent%_1.txt"
"13per%OS%cent_1.txt"
"14per%%OS%%cent_1.txt"
"15per%3cent_1.txt"
"16per%%3cent_1.txt"
"17per%Gcent_1.txt"
"18per%%Gcent_1.txt"
"21ampers&nd_1.txt"
"21ampers^&nd_1.txt"
"22ampers&&nd_1.txt"
"22ampers^&^&nd_1.txt"
"31(left_parenthesis_1.txt"
"32(both)parentheses_1.txt"
"32_rght)parenthesis_1.txt"
"41a~tilde_1.txt"
"51a^caret_1.txt"
"AÄaá^ cč^DĎ(1!)&°~!.foo~bar_1.txt"
"AÄzž^ yýS%OS%Š%%OS%%(%1!)&°~%%G!^%~2.foo~bar_1.txt"
"BÄaá^ cčD%OS%Ď%%OS%%(%1!)&°~%%G!^%~2.foo~bar_1.txt"
"elpfile_2.txt"
"new - 01exclam!ation_1.txt"
"scripts‹lpfile.txt"
"Unicode the flag or check_1.txt"
"Unicode the ⚑ or ✔ char_1.txt"
"elpfile_3.txt"

==>
```

Comment: It fails with '!' or '^' in the filename

Comment: Nice, now it seems to be bullet proof

Comment: @jeb I know that there is unsafe `md "%TESTFOLDER%"`. Would not create a folder if there is a **file of the same name**, e.g. `type nul>"%TESTFOLDER%"` :) Maybe an additional test could help:  `if not exist "%TESTFOLDER%\" goto :invalidTestFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and instead use `call` to expand `counter` variable:

```
set /a counter+=1
call %copymove% "%%i" ".\%TESTFOLDER%\%%j_%%counter%%.%Type%"
```

Comment: But now you get problems with `^`  in filenames