# Oneliner to wait for a file to be created

Tags: batch-file

I need a oneliner to wait for a file until it is created.

Is there a way to write that as a windows batch command? I cant have GOTO in it because I use pushd.

something like:

```
IF NOT EXIST \\blablabal\myfile.txt  sleep(30)
```

Comment: There would be in PowerShell... `while (-not (Test-Path myfile.txt)) { Sleep -Seconds 1 }` - how is pushd incompatible with goto?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use GOTO. Maybe you should show us your **complete** batch file

Comment: If I use it in powershell is there a way to use pushd to connect to the drive as well then?

Comment: You want a one-liner, so I suppose you want to execute it in the command prompt (`cmd`); it that true? if so, you should adapt the tags accordingly (add [tag:cmd]?); `goto` will not work in `cmd`, so I think this cannot be done in `cmd` directly...

Answer (score 3):

The solution below is a one-liner that should be executed at the command-prompt, as requested (a Batch file is *not* a "one-liner"):

```
cmd /C for /L %i in () do if not exist \\blablabal\myfile.txt (timeout /T 30 ^>NUL) else exit
```

If you wish, you may insert this line in a Batch file doubling the percent sign.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suppose that you want to [avoid `goto` statement and `:label` inside a parenthesized code block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404). Use `call` as follows:

```
(
     rem some code here
     call :waitForFile
     rem another code here
)
rem yet another code here

rem next `goto` skips `:waitForFile` subroutine; could be `goto :eof` as well
goto :nextcode
:waitForFile
  IF EXIST \\blablabal\myfile.txt goto :eof
  TIMEOUT /T 30 >NUL
goto :waitForFile

:nextcode
```

However, if you need a *oneliner* to wait for a file until it is created, written as a windows batch script: save next code snippet as `waitForFile.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
:waitForFile
  IF EXIST "%~1" ENDLOCAL & goto :eof
  TIMEOUT /T 30 >NUL
goto :waitForFile
```

Use it as follows:

- from command line window: `waitForFile "\\blablabal\myfile.txt"`
- from another batch script: `call waitForFile "\\blablabal\myfile.txt"`

Be sure that `waitForFile.bat` is present in current directory or somewhere in [`path` environment variable](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html).

Comment: `goto :mylabel` should be probably `goto :waitForFile`.

Answer (score 0):

`cmd /c "@echo off & for /l %z in () do (if EXIST c:\file.ext exit)"`

Hammers the cpu though...