# Why am I getting a "300 not expected" error?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm creating a reminder which pops up a text file when a certain period of time passes and what I want to implement is a countdown (how many seconds and minutes are left until the upcoming loop begins). Everything seems to be going fine, until the part where I try to integrate minutes and seconds into one line. It gives me a `"300 not expected here"` error after the line `echo Left (in minutes): %leftMinutes%`. Any and all help would be appreciated.

### Code

```
:Start
set /a wait = 0
set /a waitMinutes = 0
set /a left59 = %real_time% - 59 :: %real_time% is the inputed minutes,
                                 :: converted to seconds.
cls
color 0a
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Notes.txt) do (
set notes=%%a
)
cd %~dp0/Notes
start Notes.txt
goto Loop

:Loop
cls
echo Waiting for %answer_time% minutes.
echo.
set /a leftSeconds = %real_time% - %wait%
echo Left (in seconds): %leftSeconds%
set /a leftMinutes = %answer_time% - %waitMinutes%
echo Left (in minutes): %leftMinutes%
if %wait% LSS %left59% ( :: Checks if there's one more minute left in
                         :: %real_time%.
    if %wait% GEQ %left59% ( :: Checks if there's no more minutes left
                             :: in %real_time%.
        echo Left (both): %leftSeconds%
    )
    echo Left (both): %leftMinutes% and %leftSeconds%
)
timeout -t 1 -nobreak > nul
set /a wait += 1
if %wait% == 60 (
    set /a waitMinutes += 1
)
if not %wait% == %real_time% (
    goto Loop
)
if %wait% GEQ %real_time% (
    if %waitMinutes% == %answer_time% (
    taskkill -f -im Notepad.exe
    goto Start
    )
)
```

Comment: somewhere you have not initialized variable used in if condition.

Comment: @npocmaka It doesn't seem that that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404); use `REM` instead of `::`
2. Escape all `)` in `echo` commands. An unescaped closing parenthesis is still closing parenthesis even in `echo`.

For instance, instead of `echo Left (both): %leftSeconds%`, use

```
echo Left (both^): %leftSeconds%
rem            ^ note the caret
```

and, [mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis),

```
echo Left (both^): %leftMinutes% and %leftSeconds%
rem            ^ note the caret
```

Please read [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) article.

**Minimal changes** (maybe incomplete) in your script are as follows:

```
if %wait% LSS %left59% ( REM Checks if there's one more minute left in
                         REM %real_time%.
    if %wait% GEQ %left59% ( REM Checks if there's no more minutes left
                             REM in %real_time%.
        echo Left (both^): %leftSeconds%
    )
    echo Left (both^): %leftMinutes% and %leftSeconds%
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.