# Cannot print variable in cmd batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, cmd, environment

I have the following batch script

```
@echo off

setlocal

set TEST_DIR="E:/img"

:: for all png files in TEST_DIR
for /r "%TEST_DIR%" %%f in (*.png) do (

    :: print file full path
    echo TESTING %%f

    :: store the path into MY_VAR
    set MY_VAR=%%f

    :: print MY_VAR (always blank!?)
    echo TESTING %MY_VAR%

)

endlocal
```

The printing of MY_VAR always is blank. Why is that?

If the img directory contains 2 png files:
- img1.png
- img2.png

then here is the output from the console:

```
E:\img>test.cmd
TESTING E:\img\img1.png
TESTING
TESTING E:\img\img2.png
TESTING
```

Thanks

Comment: Search here for **batch-file delayed expansion**. This question has been asked (and answered) many times here in various forms.

Comment: Follow @KenWhite's advice; moreover, think about [`:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

Comment: Ok. Delayed expansion is a concept I didn't know. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Comments are ***not for extended discussion***, nor are they for off-topic arguments. I just removed 22 off-topic comments on this post. Please do not add any more.

Answer (score 2):

I corrected the script to use delayed expansion.

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set TEST_DIR="E:/img"

:: for all png files in TEST_DIR
for /r "%TEST_DIR%" %%f in (*.png) do (

    :: print file full path
    echo TESTING %%f

    :: store the path into MY_VAR
    set MY_VAR=%%f

    :: print MY_VAR
    echo TESTING !MY_VAR!

)


endlocal
```

The output is now correct.

```
E:\img>test.cmd
TESTING E:\img\img1.png
TESTING E:\img\img1.png
TESTING E:\img\img2.png
TESTING E:\img\img2.png
```

Thank you.