# using a call menu in for loop in batch kills the set variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

```
:start
CLS
echo.
echo ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
del "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe" /F /S /Q >nul 2>&1
echo %%A
pause
if exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :skip
if not exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :fix
if not exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :fix
:fix
echo fix needed on %%A
pause
esentutl /y "Olympus.exe" /d "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"
"%~dp0psexec.exe" \\%%A -accepteula "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"

:skip
echo not needed on %%A
pause
)
```

Getting confused with this and need some help. It's been a long day, I'm sure it's easy but I cant see it.
Echo %%A (3rd Line) will echo the computer name from the list of pc's in the text file I am running a driver install patch on. The minute it hits the if exist, if not exist section the %%A variable is then broken and just reports %A causing the rest of the stuff to fail.

I was trying the usual goto options but soon found out they break for loops. I was happy to find that using call routines allowed the for loop to keep going but now I'm left with a broken variable.

Comment: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

Comment: `call :fix %%A` and in `:Fix` it becomes `%1`. `esentutl` is a database repair utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next code snippet shows [*call* a subroutine](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) *logic* (however I can't attest correctness of `esentutl` and `psexec` use):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
  del "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe" /F /S /Q >nul 2>&1
  echo %%A
  pause
  if exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared\" (
    call :skip %%A
  ) else ( 
    call :fix %%A
  )
  if not exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Olympus Shared\" call :fix %%A
)
rem skip procedures
goto :SomethingNext

:fix
echo fix needed on %1
pause
esentutl /y "Olympus.exe" /d "\\%1\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"
"%~dp0psexec.exe" \\%1 -accepteula "\\%1\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"
rem return from a subroutine
exit /B

:skip
echo not needed on %1
pause
rem return from a subroutine
exit /B

:SomethingNext
```

To establish 64 or 32 bit program files structure (but not both simultaneously):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
  del "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe" /F /S /Q >nul 2>&1
  echo %%A
  pause

  rem suppose that no folder exists and (therefore) fix is necessary
  set "pf32="
  set "pf86="
  set "needFix=yes"

  rem deny the premise if either folder exists
  if exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared\" (
    set "needFix="
    set "pf32=pf32"
  )
  if exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Olympus Shared\" (
    set "needFix="
    set "pf86=pf86"
  )

  rem resume the premise if both folders exist
  if defined pf32 if defined pf64 set "needFix=yes" 

  if defined needFix ( call :fix %%A ) else ( call :skip %%A )
)
rem skip procedures
goto :SomethingNext
```

Comment: I tried that but seems to always install the patch even though the folder exists on target PC...Thanks for the answer! I'm probably missing something...

Comment: I know why, need to establish 64 or 32 bit program files structure, they are both not going to exist and also exist

Comment: `If defined ProgramFiles(x86) (echo On 64 bit) else (echo 32 bit)`

Comment: @Noodles Nope. We can't test variable existence at remote computers in such way.

Comment: Then test the folder `if exist "\\server\C$\Program Files (x86)" etc`

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("%~dp0pxhosts.txt") do (
del "\\%%A\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe" /F /S /Q >nul 2>&1
echo %%A
pause
if exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :skip "%%A"
if not exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :fix "%%A"
if not exist "\\%%A\C$\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Olympus Shared" call :fix "%%A"
)
goto :eof

:fix
echo fix needed on %~1
pause
esentutl /y "Olympus.exe" /d "\\%~1\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"
"%~dp0psexec.exe" \\%%A -accepteula "\\%~1\C$\Windows\Downloaded Program Files\Olympus.exe"

goto :eof

:skip
echo not needed on %~1
pause

goto :eof
```

Batch simply executes commands until it reaches a `goto`, `exit` or end-of-file. It has no concept of "procedures" or "functions" and `:name` is simply a label - and labels are not allowed within a block statement.

Nominally, the `metavariable` %%A is not visible with a subroutine (in fact, this appears to work) so `%%A` is passed to each of the subroutines as a quoted parameter. Within the subroutines, `%~1` retrieves and dequotes the first parameter, accessing the metavariable.

Note that `goto :eof` is used to skip over the remaining physical code in the batch file. This is understood by batch to mean "go to the end of file" - the label `:eof` is a required part of the syntax, but should not be entered as a label in the code.

I'd suggest you examine your logic however. The `if exist` will skip, but the `if not exist` will fix, so the fix is applied wherever "...Olympus Shared" is missing and skipped if it exists.