# Switch-Case for a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, switch-statement

I am currently reading "Batchography: The Art of Batch Files Programming" by Elias Bachaalany and am using one of the scripts that is demonstrating switch-case usage and how to achieve that because it is not built in.

Anyway, one of the scripts that he uses/created I cannot understand for the life of me how it getting the answers for when you input 3 or 4.

The script is below and is called [switch-case.bat](https://github.com/PassingTheKnowledge/Batchography/blob/master/switch-case.bat) if you retrieve it from the [GitHub website](https://github.com/PassingTheKnowledge/Batchography).

Can anyone explain how for switch-case-fallthrough when you use 3 or 4, the answers "fallthrough" even though there is not a case actually written at the label?

Thank you, help is greatly appreciated at explaining this.

---

```
@echo off

setlocal

set /P N=Enter number:
call :nested-if
echo.
call :switch-case
echo.
call :switch-case-combined
echo.
call :switch-case-fallthrough

goto :eof

:nested-if

echo Nested IFs...

if %N%==1 (
    echo One
) ELSE (
    if %N%==2 (
        echo Two
    ) ELSE (
        if %N%==3 (
            echo Three
        ) ELSE (
            echo Something else
        )
    )
)

echo After IFs
goto :eof

:switch-case

echo Switch/case

:: Call and mask out invalid call targets
call :switch-case-N-%N% 2>nul || (
    :: Default case
    echo Something else
)
goto :switch-case-end

:switch-case-N-1
    echo One
    goto :eof

:switch-case-N-2
    echo Two
    goto :eof

:switch-case-N-3
    echo Three
    goto :eof

:switch-case-end
echo After Switch/case

goto :eof



:switch-case-combined

echo Switch/case combined

:: Call and mask out invalid call targets
call :switch-case-N-%N% 2>nul || (
    :: Default case
    echo Something else
)
goto :switch-case-end

:switch-case-N-1
:switch-case-N-2
    echo One or two
    goto :eof


:switch-case-N-3
:switch-case-N-4
    echo Three or Four
    goto :eof

:switch-case-end
echo After Switch/case combined

goto :eof


:switch-case-fallthrough

echo Switch/case fallthrough

:: Call and mask out invalid call targets
call :switch-case-N-%N% 2>nul || (
    :: Default case
    echo Something else
)
goto :switch-case-end

:switch-case-N-1
    echo One 
    :: Fallsthrough

:switch-case-N-2
    echo Two
    goto :eof

    goto :eof

:switch-case-end
echo After Switch/case fallthrough

goto :eof
```

Comment: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`goto` searches for the label from the current position downwards. If it doesn't find the label, it continues to search from the top of the script.

So in section `switch-case-fallthrough`, `3` finds the label `:switch-case-N-3` at the `Switch/case` section above and continues there. (you can prove by changing `echo Three` in line 57 to `echo Three [here I am]`)

Same way in section switch-case-fallthrough `4` reaches line 86 above.