# If exist with multiple wildcards

Tags: batch-file

**These are the requirements:**

- Specify the wildcards to check in a variable.
- For each wildcard, verify if there are files or not. Warn the user if not (just an `echo`).
- Process the resulting files.

**What I have tried (applies to only 1 wildcard):**

```
SET wildcard=a*.txt
cd c:\somedirectory
IF EXIST "%wildcard%" (
    REM PROCESS THE FILES
) ELSE (
    ECHO There are no files that match that wildcard, please review.
)
```

This obviously only works if the wildcard is unique.

**What I have tried:**

```
SET wildcard=a*.txt b*.txt
cd c:\somedirectory
FOR %%A IN (%wildcard%) DO (
    ECHO %%A
)
```

This prints the files that match `a*.txt` or `b*.txt`. I do not want that expansion to occur. I need the actual wildcard value to go inside the loop.

With expansion, I cannot tell the user that some his wildcards do not have files. E.g. there are files `a*.txt`, but no files `b*.txt`. I need to tell that to the user. Something like:

> a*.txt: there are files.
>   b*.txt: there are no files, please review.

**Something like (this does not work, just the idea of what I am looking for):**

```
SET wildcard=a*.txt b*.txt c*.txt
cd c:\somedirectory

REM loop on the wildcards
FOR %%A IN (%wildcard%) DO (

    REM verify if there are files for that wildcard
    IF EXIST %%A (

        REM loop on the files from the specific wildcard
        FOR %%F IN (%%A) DO (
            REM PROCESS THE FILES
        )
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO This pattern %%A has no files associated
    )
)
```

Basically, can I prevent the expansion of values in `%wildcard%` inside a `IF` statement?

---

For @double-beep's comment:

- your idea of multiple `IF EXIST` statements is exactly what I want, but I do not know how many wildcards the user will want.

  ```
  SET wildcard=a*.txt b*.txt [...]
  REM this would be ok
  IF EXIST a*.txt ( ... )
  IF EXIST b*.txt ( ... )
  [...]
  ```

But how do I do that flexible, based on what the user puts in the wilcard variable?  I thought of looping on the values of wildcard, but FOR does the expansion, which I do not want.

Comment: Type `for /?` and see `/f`.

Comment: That is too complicated to write in comments, but something like `if exist a*.txt if exist b*.txt if exist c*.txt`, but then you will need multiple `else`s. Else, you could just add either a `goto` after `ECHO This pattern %%A has no files associated` and go to a custom subroutine. I am still not sure: what do you mean? Just check if many wildcard exist and if they don't do something? What is the problem here?

Comment: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404), Use `REM` instead of `::`. Moreover, use `SET wildcard=a*.txt b*.txt`

Comment: Got it JosefZ, I will do that, and edit the question.  Thanks!

Comment: @double-beep: I have added some details in the question to address your `if` statements idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this piece of code, using `call` with parameters, which do not resolve wildcards:

```cmd
@echo off
set "WildCard=a*.txt b*.txt *.vi"

call :LOOP %WildCard%
rem ...
goto :EOF


:LOOP
    if "%~1"=="" goto :EOF
    if exist "%~1" echo There are files that match the pattern: "%~1"
    shift /0
    goto :LOOP
```

Comment: Very nice!  I had not thought of using `shift`, this works perfectly!  I love this site and the community here.  Thanks!