# Problems with LSS / LEQ comparison in Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to check if the C: drive has at least a certain amount of storage left (in this case 60GB) and halt the execution if it doesn't. But I am stuck with CMD telling me that 160000 is less than 60000 and I can't figure out why.

This is the code:

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:: If disk space is less than this value, script will not be executed
SET DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB=60000

FOR /f "tokens=3" %%i IN ('dir /-c^|findstr /c:"bytes free"') DO SET "Free=%%i"
:: Free contains the bytes of storage left

SET /A DiskFreeKB=%Free:~,-3%
SET /A DiskFreeMB=%DiskFreeKB%/1024

echo Disk Space Check:
echo %DiskFreeKB% KB
echo %DiskFreeMB% MB

echo Err amount %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%

IF "%DiskFreeMB%" LSS %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB% (
    :: DiskFreeMB less than error amount
    echo.
    echo ERROR
    echo Not enough space left - %DiskFreeMB% MB of the required minimum of %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB% MB
    echo ERROR
    echo.
    
    PAUSE
    EXIT 1
) ELSE (
    echo Disk space is ok
    :: (Continue with other code)
)
```

This is the console's output:
[image]

Comment: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

Comment: Remove the quotes around `%DiskFreeMB%`…

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, I've removed them

Comment: @aschipfl that sadly didn't change anything

Comment: Well, `if "%DiskFreeMB%" lss %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%` can never be true since the quotes are also part of the compared expressions, which are considered as strings then…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use [wmic](/questions/tagged/wmic) for this task:

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" Volume Where "DriveLetter='%SystemDrive%' And FreeSpace >='60000000000'" Get FreeSpace 2> NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "[0-9]" 1> NUL || Exit 1
@Rem Your code here
@Echo Enough Space & Pause
```

You could beautify that if you like

```batch-file
@"%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe" Volume Where ^
 "DriveLetter='%SystemDrive%' And FreeSpace >='60000000000'" ^
 Get FreeSpace 2> NUL | "%__AppDir__%findstr.exe" "[0-9]" 1> NUL || Exit 1
@Rem Your code here
@Echo Enough Space & Pause
```

*In both examples, the last two lines are for informational purposes.*

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the difference instead.

Subtract the Free space from the minimum required amount, and if it is `<= 0`, then you don't have enough space.

```
SET /A delta=%DiskFreeMB% - %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%
if %delta% LEQ 0 ( echo Out of Space )
```

---

#### Here is a short little test program

```
@echo off
echo Test1:  Sufficient Disk Space
set DiskFreeMB=600
set DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB=500
SET /A ErrorDelta=%DiskFreeMB% - %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%
if %ErrorDelta% LEQ 0 ( echo Out of Space )
echo.

echo Test2: Not enough space.
set DiskFreeMB=400
set DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB=500
SET /A ErrorDelta=%DiskFreeMB% - %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%
if %ErrorDelta% LEQ 0 ( echo Out of Space )
echo.

echo Test2: Exactly Full
set DiskFreeMB=500
set DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB=500
SET /A ErrorDelta=%DiskFreeMB% - %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%
if %ErrorDelta% LEQ 0 ( echo Out of Space )
echo.
```

Output:

```
Test1:  Sufficient Disk Space

Test2: Not enough space.
Out of Space

Test2: Exactly Full
Out of Space
```

Comment: I'm now getting the error `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`. My modified IF looks like this: `SET /A ErrorDelta=%DiskFreeMB% - %DISK_SPACE_ERROR_AMOUNT_MB%  
IF %ErrorDelta% LEQ 0 ( echo Out of Space )`