# CMD forgets file location (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Tags: sorting, batch-file, cmd

Started programming a little while ago, and wanted to do a simple program that can sort through images via user input. I wanted to do this via cmd/powershell because I assume it'd be the faster way to do it and it's easier than, say, C or C++ (Please note I'm not the best at this)

I currently have the following:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd "C:\img\Unsorted"

:SORT
FOR /R %%f IN (*.jpg *.png *.gif *.jpeg) DO (
    echo Current file is: %%f
    start "" "D:\Downloads\ImageGlass_Kobe_8.6.7.13_x64\ImageGlass.exe" %%f
    CHOICE /N /C 123 /M "PICK A NUMBER (1 (Folder A), 2 (Folder B), or 3(Delete))"%1
    IF ERRORLEVEL ==3 GOTO THREE
    IF ERRORLEVEL ==2 GOTO TWO
    IF ERRORLEVEL ==1 GOTO ONE
    GOTO END

    :THREE
    echo Current file is: %%f ::This is where the output is: 'Current file is: %f' which clearly indicates it forgot the file
    move %%f "C:\img\Delete"
    echo To the trash it goes!
    taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
    GOTO END

    :TWO
    echo Folder B Selected
    taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
    move %%f "C:\img\FolderB"
    GOTO END

    :ONE
    echo Folder A
    taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
    move %%f "C:\img\FolderA"
    GOTO END
)

:END
goto SORT
```

The problem i'm running is that it returns "The system cannot find the file specified." Whenever the move command is sent (because it somehow looses the file info??)

Comment: [**Never** use `:label` nor `:: label-like comment` inside a command block enclosed in `()` parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32147995/3439404)

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the comment was added for the post specifically and is not part of the program! So, it still doesn't run well

Comment: `%%f` is not defined outside the `for` loop.

Comment: the correct syntax for `if` is `if errorlevel 3  ...`. Your wrong syntax just happens to work because `==` is interpreted like  a whitespace during parsing. Don't rely on this "autocorrection"

Comment: Huh, so how could I define it?

Comment: Thanks Stephan! I'll try to do that and see if adjusting the syntax works

Comment: Forget about `goto` and labels in loops (or other code blocks) - `goto`'s break your loop and labels have undefined behaviour, probably also breaking your loop. You have to change your logic to not use labels and `goto`s within the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CHOICE /N /C 123Q /M "PICK A NUMBER (1 (Folder A), 2 (Folder B), or 3(Delete))"%1
set "choicemade=option!errorlevel!"
taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe
if /i "!choicemade!"=="option4" goto :eof

if /i "!choicemade!"=="option3" (
 echo Current file is: %%f
 move "%%f" "C:\img\Delete"
 echo To the trash it goes!
)
```

(repeat for options 2 & 1)

Notes: Because `delayedexpansion` has been invoked, the "variable" `!errorlevel!` is the value of `errorlevel` as it has changed within the loop, and similarly for `choicemade`.

Since you want to `taskkill` regardless of the option taken, include it here - **After** setting `choicemade`

I've added option `Q` for **Q**uit. Since it's the 4th character in the `/c` string, pressing `q` will set errorlevel to **4**

":eof" (with the colon) is defined by `cmd` as physical end-of-file

`if /i` makes the match case-insensitive.

`move "%%f" ....` because `%%f` may contain spaces.

The `goto end` statements can be omitted so that the `for` loop merely proceeds to the next value.

IMHO, it's not good practice to use `cmd`'s keywords (like `sort`) as labels or variable-names.

"loose" means "not tight" or "unleash". "lose" means "not win" or "to be deprived of, or cease to have or retain (something)". You need to lose the extra `o`,

Comment: Thanks for everything! I turn around the code by just making a big line everytime like this: IF ERRORLEVEL 3  echo echo "To the trash it goes!" && move %%f "C:\img\Delete" && taskkill /IM ImageGlass.exe

And it works but I will look at your option to see how it works. Also, thanks for the Taskkill optimization, haven't thought about it! And thanks for the loose vs lose clarification, not a native english speaker so it always helps!